# Is it permisable to work in a company which supports LGBT rights?

Tags: islamic-basis, work, homosexuality, studying

salam alaykum dear community,

I am an IT student a while ago a company contacted me and asked for a small discussion about future positions in this company. So i agreed and after i agreed i saw on their website that they support LGBT rights (they just support them but it is not a lgbt company which is primarly focused on LGBT just a IT company which is okay with lgbt people).

I thought that it may be interessting for me to see what they will say. I thought of even a bad experience is a good one but i dont want to support the LGBT community in that case first questions in my mind where what if they want from me to make a website where LGBT is promoted. When it comes to LGBT i dont support them but i am not rude with them either. I am neutral in that case.

Question: is it permissable to work in such a company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Praise be to Allah,

Assalamualaikum,

It is permissible to work in the company as long as you yourself aren’t involved in anything that is supporting LGBT rights. However, if they request you to support LGBT rights then tell them that you cannot get involved in it because of religious beliefs and if that is not possible I suggest that you leave the company and find another job

May Allah (SWT) help you and make things easy for you

Comment: Jazak Allah khair brother this helped me :)